# how can i assign a java script element id to a java code

Tags: java, javascript

Am trying to assign a java script element id to the integer like this,

```
int PAGE_SIZE =%> <script>document.getElementById('t1')</script><%;
```

and in my java code am assigning some dynamic value for the PAGE_SIZE varilable, Now with this id "t1" can i pass the integer value dynamically to a select box like this,

```
<select id="t1">
```

Hope you understand what am trying to say.

Kindly suggest me how to do this.

Comment: Just explain it little brief with what you tried!

Comment: am just trying to pass the integer value to the select box through the script element id is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fundamental** -

```
Javascript runs in client browser. and Java runs in server.
```

are you trying to run your javascript code in server? :)

Comment: ya exactly what you said is it possible in any way?

Comment: @sathya when javascript need to interact with java. you have to send request to server through get or post request.

Comment: When we write jsp, we write java and javascript all in same page but actually jsp get compiled and bring output as raw html which goes to client and run. you can pass value java to javascript.

Comment: but the above process i said in same page both the int decleration and select box are in same page i cant use any request

Comment: For html/javascript to java you need to pass request to server. There is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer your id as a parameter in the url, which you could then parse in servlet || Spring MVC controller action, etc. Look at the urls with parameters, for example www.example.com?param1=1&param2=2  ..

There are some examples for you:
[How to pass parameter to servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234090/how-to-pass-parameter-to-servlet)

[How do I pass multiple parameter in URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943635/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameter-in-url)

Read about the HttpRequest and HttpResponse - should help.

Comment: am just trying to pass the integer value to the select box through the script element id is it possible?